# How can I use a different .net language (F#) for asp.net vnext

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm interested how I can use a different .NET language (F# for instance) and still target asp.net vNext.
One way I can think of is making a F# NuGet package and reference it but this still does not allow you to use F# or any other .net language for all the implementation (I'm not talking about the razor pages here).

I mean it seems that when you do a `k run` it simply compiles all the *.cs files using Roslyn and call it a day. No way to change anything or at least I could not find a way.

This means the only other option to target asp.net vnext completely from another .net language (not Roslyn supported meaning not C# or vb.net) is to somehow compile an assembly referencing the asp.net vnext assemblies and run it in IIS? Thus bypassing the `k run` or the `k web` defined in `project.json`?

Comment: See http://blog.alxandr.me/2014/11/23/f-in-asp-net-5-the-good-the-bad-and-the-really-ugly/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After playing more with the samples and making some tests in iisexpress I can confirm that you can use F# and run an F# based asp.net vnext web app.

I used a simple sample that was just responding from the Startup class in configure with a string. I compiled it and referenced the Microsoft.AspNet.Http assembly from the user kre packages folder. 
I used AspNet.Loader.dll from the Helios in bin folder and also copied there the f# assembly and it all works well under iisexpress.

Comment: can you expand on this? what was involved in responding from the Startup class with a string?

Comment: You should write a blog on this!